# Jquery .live issue

Tags: jquery, live

I have the following snippet of code.

HTML (simplified):

```
    <tr>
    <td><div id="insert_24" class="insert">Invoegen</div></td>
    </tr>
```

On which a JS function is running (simplified) to retrieve the data from the form, add it to the database and then update the form/table with the correct class & ID's:

```
    $(".insert").click(function() {
        // current field, is the id: insert_24
        // layer is retrieved in the function: 24
        // Full table has the id 'canvas'

        // do something
        // Insert into database

        console.log('insert-'+layer);
        $("#"+ current_field).removeClass("insert").addClass("delete").html('delete').attr('id', 'delete_'+layer);
        $("table#canvas tr:last").attr('id', 'row_'+layer);
    });
```

Directly after this code I also have the code to delete a line (simplified):

```
    $(".delete").live("click", function() {
        // do something
        // Insert into database

        console.log('delete-'+layer);
        $("#row_"+ layer).remove();         
    });
```

The insert works perfectly, but when I look at the console log functions, on 'insert', also the 'delete' function is being triggered directly after the insert, which doesn't make sense. I only clicked the `<div>` once.

Which step/setting am I missing to have this function work in the correct way?

Comment: jsfiddle please? -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: FYI, you can replace `$("#"+ current_field)` with `$(this)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your `click()` handler to `return false;`, or:

```
$(".insert").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code here
});
```

`.live()` works by attaching a handler at the document level and waiting for events to bubble up - at which time it checks if the original target element matches the selector you used. So when a click occurs it first triggers the (non-live) click handler and then bubbles up to trigger the live handler.

Note also that removing the `"insert"` class from the element will not stop your click handler from firing on that element. You'd need to either unbind the click handler (from within the handler) or change that one to a live handler too.

Note that `.live()` is way out of date. You should update to use the delegated syntax of the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead..

Comment: Good catch on that last part. A better solution would probably be to have one handler that just checks `$(this).hasClass("insert")`.

Comment: Just to be clear, `.on()` uses a similar approach as `.live()`, so it suffers from the same original problem.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. +1 to you too - you answered first. And yes, switching to `.on()` wouldn't make any difference on this problem, but I recommend it in a general sense since it is slightly more efficient and because `.live()` was deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: Excellent solution. Sometimes they are so simple. This works and I will definitely will look into the .on() function to replace the live to keep on with the newest solution.

Comment: If you take a look at the `.live()` doco page it tells you how to update. (Note that `.on()` can be called with several different types of parameters, so make sure you get the right combination for delegated event handling.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".insert").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // current field, is the id: insert_24
    // layer is retrieved in the function: 24
    // Full table has the id 'canvas'

    // do something
    // Insert into database

    console.log('insert-'+layer);
    $("#"+ current_field).removeClass("insert").addClass("delete").html('delete').attr('id', 'delete_'+layer);
    $("table#canvas tr:last").attr('id', 'row_'+layer);
});
```

What's happening is that the click event is bubbling up to the document. `.live()` has a handler on the document that checks whether the target of the event matches the selector. After the click handler completes, the class of the DIV has changed to `delete`, so this check succeeds, and it runs the handler.